# How do I deploy an existing web app project to Azure using Visual Studio but no Azure Emulator?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

I have an existing project with three web apps (two web API and a front end). I would like to deploy to Azure all three with a single click of Publish using the Publish Web wizard.

I installed the Azure SDK and tried to create a new Cloud Service, but this install the VMs and the storage emulator, that I don't need at all and slows down my PC.

I tried with Azure Resource Group to add to an existing project, but the Deploy button remains disabled, like it failed to connect to the web site project.
What is the recommended way to do this?

I am using Visual Studio 2015

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to install the emulator for the deployment to work, just download the parts you need from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178 (assuming you want SDK 2.7).

It's not really clear from your question if you want to deploy a Cloud Service or a Web App. If you want to deploy a Cloud Service, you can add all 3 projects as roles and they will all be published within a single deployment (just one click to Publish). But, if what you want is to deploy them as web apps, you will need to do it in 3 different apps, which means 3 clicks to publish.

Comment: I would like to use Web Apps, but I was going to see if Cloud Service worked as well - thanks for clarifying the differences.